# Creating a scanf to format a text file

Tags: c, regex, scanf

I have to format a line like this:

```
<Ana Baldwin>        gpa    3.71      <Modesto Adventist Academy>       SAT math  553     SAT reading  766
```

to look like this:

```
Ana Baldwin   3.71   Modesto Adventist Academy      553    766
```

My code for this so far is:

```
int main(void)
{
    int     matchcount;
    char    name[20], GPA[6], school[30], SATmath[10], SATreading[10];

    char    dontcareGPA, dontcareSATmath, dontcareSATreading;
    char    dontcare1, dontcare3;
    char    dontcare2[40], dontcare4[40];

    matchcount = scanf ("%[^<]%c%[^>]%c%c%[^<]%c%[^>]%c%[^0-9]%[0-9]%c%[^0-9]%[0-9] ",
                                  &dontcare1,
                                  &name[0], &dontcare2[0], &dontcareGPA,
                                  &GPA[0], &dontcare3,
                                  &school[0], &dontcare4[0], &dontcareSATmath,
                                  &SATmath[0], &dontcareSATreading,
                                  &SATreading[0]);
    while  ((matchcount != 0) && (matchcount != EOF))
    {
        printf ("%-20.20s %-6.6s %-30.30s %-10.10s %-10.10s\n", name, GPA, school, SATmath, SATreading);

        matchcount = scanf ("%[^<]%c%[^>]%c%c%[^<]%c%[^>]%c%[^0-9]%[0-9]%c%[^0-9]%[0-9] ",
                                      &dontcare1,
                                      &name[0], &dontcare2[0], &dontcaregpa,
                                      &GPA[0], &dontcare3,
                                      &school[0], &dontcare4[0], &dontcareSATmath,
                                      &SATmath[0], &dontcareSATreading,
                                      &SATreading[0]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I'm having the most difficulty understanding the different scanf formatting.

Comment: The question seems to broad, ask the concrete doubts you have about the format strings (for example how to read a string between brackets, etc...)

Comment: I understand when putting %[^<] or %[^>] will read up to the brackets. Will this read them into a character using the scanf?

Answer (score 2):

You've got some good ideas, and some not so good ones.  You can avoid the "don't care" inputs by suppressing the corresponding assignments with a `*` in the format string.  Alternatively, you can craft the format string so that they're altogether unnecessary.

You currently have:

```
matchcount = scanf ("%[^<]%c%[^>]%c%c%[^<]%c%[^>]%c%[^0-9]%[0-9]%c%[^0-9]%[0-9] ",
                              &dontcare1,
                              &name[0], &dontcare2[0], &dontcareGPA,
                              &GPA[0], &dontcare3,
                              &school[0], &dontcare4[0], &dontcareSATmath,
                              &SATmath[0], &dontcareSATreading,
                              &SATreading[0]);
```

The first format item looks for one or more non-`<` characters, but if the first character of input is `<`, the matching fails immediately.  If there is a blank or other character before the `<`, then some of the conversions would work.  However, it gets very complex to decide what would be included in which data. I think the third `%c` would read a blank; the following `%[^>]` would read blanks, `gpa`, the `<` and the school name up to the `>`, which is not quite what you had in mind.

You really need something like:

```
matchcount = scanf(" <%19[^>]> gpa %5s <%29[^>]> SAT math %9[0-9] reading %9[0-9]",
                   &name[0], &GPA[0], &school[0], &SATmath[0], &SATreading[0]);
```

I've limited the strings to one less than the declared size of the variables.

Your loop condition is currently:

```
while  ((matchcount != 0) && (matchcount != EOF))
```

It needs to be:

```
while (matchcount == 5)
```

Almost always, you want to test that you got the expected number of converted items.  You really want to avoid that big repeat of the `scanf()` statement too.  I don't suppose you've learned about structures yet, so I think I'd write a function:

```
int get_info(char *name, char *GPA, char *school, char *SATmath, char *SATreading)
{
    return scanf(" <%19[^>]> gpa %5s <%29[^>]> SAT math %9[0-9] reading %9[0-9]",
                 name, GPA, school, SATmath, SATreading);
}
```

to encapsulate the `scanf()` statement, and then use it in the loop condition:

```
while (get_info(name, GPA, school, SATmath, SATreading) == 5)
     printf(…);
```

Comment: And use `name` instead of `&name[0]` in the `scanf` call. Similarly for other arguments.

Comment: That's a style choice, @RSahu.  The advantage of the `&strvar[0]` notation is that each argument starts with an `&`, and the `[0]` subscript correctly avoids passing a `char **` or `char (*)[20]` to `scanf()` instead of a `char *`. So it gives a simple visual check: do all the arguments to `scanf()` other than the format string have an `&` in front.  Yes — good!  No — bad; mistake.  So, while I would not normally code like that, it has definite merits for someone learning C.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, I agree that it is a style choice. Thanks for adding the extra clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit confusing, as your title says *text file* but your code uses `printf()`/`scanf()`. Technically there's not issue, but generally we use `f...()` series when working with files.

Leaving that part, if you don't mind a second approach, other than using `scanf()`, you can follow the following steps:

1. read the input using using [`fgets()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets).
2. tokenize the input using [`strtok()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtok) using proper delimiter.
3. based on the received token [valid or NULL], copy the token to the storage variable. Optionally, you can use `strtol()`/ `strtod()` to convert to `int`/`float`/`double`.

<sup>Note: while using `fgets()`, you should some precaution to handle the traliing `\n`.</sup>

Comment: We're using the terminal to read in the text file. 

So in this case my file name is readapplicant.c 

I'll create a gcc -o readapplicant readapplicant.c 

Then read the text file using ./readapplicant < applicant.txt 

Our professor is wanting us to only use the scanf/printf commands.